extract a multifile .zip archive on Linux (with gunzip)
I have a large file in Wondows and neetd to transport it to a Linux server via the linux /tmp folder that has onlz limited capacity.
In order to do so I created a zip with 7zip on my Windows host (where I can not install any additional tools on, due to company resrictions) and split that into 4 files.
largefile.zip.001
largefile.zip.002
largefile.zip.003
largefile.zip.004

extracting the main ~.zip.001 with 7zip on Windows again, seems to pull the data from the other files ~.002-.004. So it somehow recognizez the relation among them.
now how can I achive the same thing on the linux target? gunzip largefile.zip.001 as well as gunzip largefile.zip.00{1,2,3,4} resulted into a unexpected end of file error.
Did I just not identify the right option in man gunzip, or can anybody recommened anything else to do this?

edit: I can neither install anything beyond the mere basics (and the below mentioned 7zip for linux is not one of them) on my rhel server due to lack of sudo privileges.

that is how I mangaged to do this.
on my Windows local laptop with git bash

split the original unzipped file with
split -b 2500m -a 2 -d large_file.sql large_file.sql-

compress all of them with ...
for i in $(seq 0 7) ; do gzip large_file.sql-0"${i}" ; done

manoever those over to my rhel server server (using WinSCP)


On my rhel server

extract them there with ...
for i in $(seq 0 7) ; do echo gunzip large_file.sql-0${i}.gz ; done
put then together into one single file again
cat large_file.sql-0{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} > /path/to/large_file.sql

I am not 1000% certain, whether the cat (#5) part would have worked with a binary file rather then text, but I think it should.

Why don't you just use 7zip on Linux?
p7zip packages are in the universe repository in Ubuntu so make sure that you have enabled it using this command:
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update

Use the following command to install 7zip support in Ubuntu and Debian based distributions.
sudo apt install p7zip-full p7zip-rar

In the terminal, you can extract a split zip archive file using this command:
7z x largefile.zip.001 -tiso.split -o<output_dir>


Since p7zip is still at v. 16.02, AFAIK, and Windows 7-Zip, on which p7zip is based, is at v. 24.06, you might want to download the latest from https://7-zip.org and run it under wine, which works well on my PC's. However, that will require using wine as a prefix when using 7-Zip in terminal.

thx for the pointer and sorry I for being not specific enough (habe eddaed this info above now) ... I can neither install anything out of the usual on my server (due to other company restrictions), so 7zip is out of the game.
